# Defining geometry with transformation groups

Tags: geometry

In the book on Computer Graphics: Theory and Practice, the author gave the following description for Geometry:

"The transformation group method was formally introduced by the German mathematician Felix Klein (1849–1925), who was inspired by the principle of overlapping, used implicitly by Euclid in the demonstration of some of his geometric theorems. In this method, a geometry consists of a space $S$ (the points in the geometry) and a group $G$ of transformations of $S$, that is, one-to-one maps $g : S \to S$ that are continuous in both directions."

I haven't found such definition in any another source. I was wondering if it is "correct", or if it is just a simplification by the author. I've tried searching Klein's Geometry, but the definition seem quite more convoluted, involving cosets and Lie Algebras.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: It is a great simplification.

Comment: Yes, it is a simplification. You can start by reading https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program

Comment: The idea of transformation can be traced back to Euclides (e.g., his definition of case of equality for triangles) but it is not until the 19th century that transformations became a "mathematical object of study". Poncelet in the 1820s for projective transformations, Steiner in the years 1830-1840 for the transformation called "inversion" predate Klein by some little decades : these important examples have surely helped F. Klein to build his brilliant visionnary "Erlangen program".